# Django Admin: adding an icon with assigned JS above the textarea

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to add a couple of icons (or buttons) with simple JS functionality
(e.g. wrapping selected text in HTML tags with particular class). Like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLjiA.jpg)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options when using django admin libraries such as suit or jet.

But if you use django default admin, you have to edit your admin template.

You can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) in django docs to overriding admin template.

i.e. if you want to override `change_form.html`, you can simply add the html file and override it.

And there, you can add your own button inside the specific block.

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
    <!-- Add your own button or icons here or anywhere you want -->
    <li>
        <a href="">Your button</a>
    </li>
    {% if has_absolute_url %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'admin:view_on_site' content_type_id original.pk %}" class="viewsitelink">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using django default admin, is it possible to define the position of an icon or button above the textarea? In your example the button appears near to History button on the right.

Comment: @corpus It's possible but bad idea. Basically, django admin share every pages (and also every elements) for one template. So, I think you have two choice - 1. customize your django admin for specific model's textarea field. 2. make your own admin template for that page. Maybe first one is much simple.